# Love2d drawing grid and manipulating it i have few problems

Tags: lua, love2d

Hello i made grid code but it doesn't look like how i wanted to, i want to to be will look like down there i tried a lot but i wasn't able to find right formula to do that

Here is my code

```
function love.load()
  num = 32-- how many cell are going to be in each axis
  w = 20
  h = 20
  color = {128, 128, 128}
  backgroundcolor = {192, 192, 192}
end


function love.update(dt)

end

function love.draw()
  for y = 1, num do
    for x = 1, num do
      if (x + y)%2 == 0 then
        love.graphics.setColor(unpack(color))
      else
        love.graphics.setColor(unpack(backgroundcolor))
      end
      love.graphics.rectangle("fill", (x - 1)*w ,(y - 1)*h, w, h)
    end
  end
end
```

Result:

[image]

I want to achieve this each cell is 16 x 16.

Note: I don't want to use 2 x 2 cell i need 32 x 32 of them that is the problem i am facing right now.

[image]

Comment: Well i figure out formula but is there is way to simplify this (x%8 <= 4 and x%8 ~= 0 and y%8 <= 4 and y%8 ~= 0) or ((x%8 > 4 or x%8 == 0 ) and (y%8 > 4 or y%8 == 0))

Comment: `(math.floor((x-1)/4)+math.floor((y-1)/4))%2 == 0`

Comment: Sir can u explain how it works ?